# remover parte de um array de objetos php

Tags: php, array, string, api, foreach

Boa noite.
Estou tentando fazer um foreach de uma resposta de api.
Ela me vem assim:

```js
{
  "page": 1,
  "results": [
    {
      "adult": false,
      "backdrop_path": "/9WlJFhOSCPnaaSmsrv0B4zA8iUb.jpg",
      "genre_ids": [
        28,
        27,
        53
      ],
      "id": 503736,
      "original_language": "en",
      "original_title": "Army of the Dead",
      "overview": "Após um surto de zumbis em Las Vegas, nos Estados Unidos, um grupo de mercenários faz uma aposta final, aventurando-se na zona de quarentena para tentar realizar o maior assalto de todos os tempos.",
      "poster_path": "/vARBnfGEcsb83gdtK0JHb8QaLio.jpg",
      "release_date": "2021-05-14",
      "title": "Army of the Dead: Invasão em Las Vegas",
      "video": false,
      "vote_average": 6.6,
      "vote_count": 128,
      "popularity": 313.796,
      "media_type": "movie"
    },
    {
      "adult": false,
      "backdrop_path": "/6ELCZlTA5lGUops70hKdB83WJxH.jpg",
      "genre_ids": [
        28,
        14,
        12
      ],
      "vote_count": 2563,
      "original_language": "en",
      "original_title": "Mortal Kombat",
      "poster_path": "/w8BVC3qrCWCiTHRz4Rft12dtQF0.jpg",
      "id": 460465,
      "video": false,
      "title": "Mortal Kombat",
      "vote_average": 7.6,
      "overview": "Nova aventura baseada no videogame Mortal Kombat. Na história, um jovem que nunca treinou artes marciais acaba envolvido em um gigantesco torneio de luta envolvendo guerreiros da Terra e lutadores e outras dimensões.",
      "release_date": "2021-04-07",
      "popularity": 2112.759,
      "media_type": "movie"
    },
    {
      "adult": false,
      "backdrop_path": "/gUttUEqsrvaMlK5oL5TSQ54iE96.jpg",
      "genre_ids": [
        80,
        18,
        9648,
        53
      ],
      "id": 520663,
      "original_language": "en",
      "original_title": "The Woman in the Window",
      "overview": "A Dr.ª Anna Fox é uma alcoólatra reclusa que passa os dias em seu apartamento em Nova York assistindo a filmes antigos e observando seus vizinhos. Quando a família Russell se muda para o prédio da frente, ela passa a espionar o que seria a família perfeita, até testemunhar uma cena chocante que muda sua vida.",
      "poster_path": "/8BasMP1hUZtDx0khdbHBkVZhKjJ.jpg",
      "release_date": "2021-05-14",
      "title": "A Mulher na Janela",
      "video": false,
      "vote_average": 6.3,
      "vote_count": 545,
      "popularity": 366.666,
      "media_type": "movie"
    },.....
```

Ela continua. Para receber eu usei :

```js
$json = file_get_contents($url);
```

Ja tentei com json_recode, com e sem true.
Porem quando tento ler com foreach ele me retorna somente escrito

> Array

tentei com o seguinte codigo

> foreach($json as $result)
> {
> echo $result[0].'
> ';
> }

Ja tentei de diversas formas, ja tentei fazer um replace do começo {pages:1, results: porem retorna que a classStd nao permite.
Consegui receber os dados da API mas nao consigo tratar.

Comment: Utilize `$result = json_decode($json, true);` para transformar o *JSON* em um *Array*. Se você tentar utilizar o `echo` em um *Array*, o valor imprimido será *Array*. É necessário passar um índice como `foreach($json['results'] as $result) { echo $result['backdrop_path']; }`

Comment: Show. Deu certo meu amigo. agr é tratar cada key individual. Obrigado. Se quiser mandar como resposta pra eu poder avaliar melhor.